# Can't update document value in mongoDB with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, object

I'm trying to get the value of a field form that I'm sending to a subroute and use it to update the database collection. I can get the value of the form perfectly and work with it, the problem comes when I only want to update the fields that are not empty.

server.js

```
app.post("/updProject", function(request, response){

    var project = { name : request.body.project_name };
    var test = {};
    if(request.body.new_project_name != ""){
        test['name'] = request.body.new_project_name;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_description != ""){
        test['description'] = request.body.new_project_description;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_site != ""){
        test['view'] = request.body.new_project_site;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_code != ""){
        test['code'] = request.body.new_project_code;
    }
    var data = { $set: [test] };
    console.log(data);

    collection.updateOne(project, data, function(error, collection){
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("Record edited successfully");
    });
    return response.redirect('/');
});
```

MongoDB error on syntax after only placing data in the description field:

```
{ '$set': [ { description: 'helloasd' } ] }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to extend an object using string concatenation resulting in the object being converted to a string. You want to do the following: `test['description'] = request.body.new_project_description`. That scheme also applies to the other property assignments you have in the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but now mongoDB throws this error: { '$set': [ { description: 'helloasd' } ] } I think its because the syntaxs should not have [] how can I fix it?

Comment: I am not to familiar with MongoDB but you might want to remove the `[]` so you have `{ '$set': { description: 'helloasd' } }` instead of `{ '$set': [ { description: 'helloasd' } ] }`.

Comment: Yes, thats the syntaxis I need, but I don't know how to remove them while showing the content of the variable

Comment: Simply do: `let data = { $set: test }`.

Comment: Thanks, solved, the record is updated successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Palladium02:

```
    if(request.body.new_project_name != ""){
        test['name'] = request.body.new_project_name;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_description != ""){
        test['description'] = request.body.new_project_description;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_site != ""){
        test['view'] = request.body.new_project_site;
    }
    if(request.body.new_project_code != ""){
        test['code'] = request.body.new_project_code;
    }
    let data = { $set: test };
    console.log(data);
```